# How to avoid the output zero when "x" is not a number?

Tags: c++

I'm making a numbers' application that tells if it's positive, negative, nil or not a number. I only have a problem with the "not a number" condition. How can I tell the computer to show the inputted characters if "x" is not a number?

```
#include <std_lib_facilities.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int x;
    cout << "x= ";
    x;
    cin >> x;
    if (x > 0)
    {
        cout << x;
        cout << " is a positive number";
    }
    if (x == 0)
    {
        cout << x;
        cout << " is nil";
    }
    if (x < 0)
    {
        cout << "(";
        cout << x;
        cout << ")";
        cout << " is a negative number";
    }
    if (cin.good())
    {
    }
    else
    {
        x != 0;
        cout << "x";
        cout << " is not a number";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

For some reason it shows the output as a zero and not as I wrote it.

Comment: x !=0;  what is it supposed to do?

Comment: `std::variant` or throw exceptions

Comment: @oblivion i am a beginner, and i thought when i insert x !=0 it won't show zero in the output

Comment: @Sandburg where to add std::variant

Comment: Are you guessing `x != 0` removes this case? Have a look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert `assert(x != 0);`

Comment: okay I will, *thanks* @Sandburg

Comment: About `std::variant` (c++17) its a container that makes possible to build a type which would be either an `int` or a NaN (type to define).

Comment: x !=0; just compares x with 0 and returns a Boolean  which you don't store anywhere

Comment: You know you can combine printing like `cout << "(" << x << ") is a negative number\n";` right?

Comment: If `x` is not an integer, then `cin.fail()` will be set. You can handle that case and after `cin.clear()`, you can read all characters waiting for input with `getline`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And one example so you will know how to do this with try-catch. You can say that everything that user enters is a string, and then you can try and parse this as int. However, there is possibility that user will not enter string, so you need to try to parse and catch any error if it occurs. if error occurs, then user did not enter a number, but something completely different. If user entered the number, then you are good to go, to check if it is positive, negative or 0.

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    std::string x;
    std::cout << "Enter a number: " << std::endl;

    try {
        std::cin>>x;
        int number = std::stoi(x);
        if (number < 0) {
            std::cout << "Negative number" << std::endl;
        }
        else if (number > 0) {
            std::cout << "Positive number" << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cout << "You entered number 0" << std::endl;
        }
    }catch(...) {
        std::cout << "Not a number!" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just figured that out. Thanks Sandburg.

```
#include <std_lib_facilities.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x;
    cout<<"x= ";x;
    cin>> x;
    if (cin.good()) 
    {
        if (x>0)
        {
            cout<< x;
            cout<<" is a positive number";
        }

        if (x==0)
        {
            cout<< x;
            cout<<" is nil";
        }

        if (x<0)
        {
            cout<<"(";
            cout<< x;
            cout<<")";
            cout<<" is a negative number";
        }
    } 
    else
    {
        cout<< "x";
        cout<< " is not a number";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Beware of the indentation, it's unpleasant to read. Have a look at http://format.krzaq.cc/

Comment: @Sandburg sorry for bothering again, but what's the function of the inputted characters, like if i wrote "test". `cout<< function` is `cout<<"test"`